# How should units be treated?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, units, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

First sorry I don't know how to properly use this page yet. Secondly, in a electricity problem I've found the following expression:

$$(q_1*q_2)/r_1 +(q_1*q_3)/(r_1+r_2)+(q_2*q_3)/r_2=0\tag{1},$$

and I have to solve for $r_2$ knowing all the other values.

The charges are given in nC and the distances in cm so I tried the following to avoid scientific notation and simplify the calculations,

$$q_1=a\text{ nC} ,q_2=b \text{ nC} ,q_3=c\text{ nC} ,r_1=x\text{ cm} ,r_2=y\text{ cm}\tag{2},$$

thus

$$(a \text{ nC}*b\text{ nC})/x\text{ cm} + (a \text{ nC}*b\text{ nC})/x\text{ cm}+y\text{ cm} + (b\text{ nC}*c\text{ nC})/y\text{ cm}=0\tag{3},$$

that implies

$$ab/x +ac/(x+y) + bc/y=0\tag{4}.$$

Then just substitute and solve for $y$ but the problem is that this gives me imaginary solutions.
I have the solution of the problem and the only difference in the procedure is this part, I mean it used the scientific notation and transformed the cm to m and obtained a real number as answer.
My question is if I'm missing something about how units work and how should I think about them in this case and if I've done something illegal.

Comment: Removing units in this way (which is OK but not the usual way of doing things) has nothing to do with getting imaginary rather than real solutions. You must have done something wrong when you solved one (or both) of them. The two equations are obviously the same except for the names of the variables!

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to solve for $r_2$ algebraically and only *then* evaluate it by putting in values with units.

Comment: That's what I first tried but I couldn't the answer is to difficult for solving the problem (I made Wolfram solve for r2 and the answer is too long).Even the book suggest me too replace the values and then solve for r2 that's why This doubt came to me.I mean I know how to solve it what I'm asking is why this is invalid is not really clear for me Thank you

Comment: It just becomes a quadratic equation. You don’t need a computer to solve a quadratic equation. If you are not getting a real solution then either your equation is wrong (likely) or your problem (which you never stated) doesn’t have a solution (unlikely, since it’s homework).

Comment: Obviously I made something wrong,and I know it's this part because the rest of the procedure is the same as in the book, and ai know hoylw to solve it ,nut what I'm asking is why I can't treat units like variables

Comment: Units are *part* of variables. For example, $q_1$ might be 7 nC. But there is little point (at least in this kind of problem), and much wasted effort, in writing $q_1$ as $a$ nC. It simply replaces a dimensional variable with a dimensionless variable. We sometimes do this in physics, but usually when the dimensionless variable has some physical significance as a ratio, like measuring atomic distances in Bohr radii. SI units are completely arbitrary have no physical significance, so de-dimensionalizing SI variables is fairly uncommon.